# Django ORM: pre-filtering related fields inside a queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

Imagine I have two models, `A` and `B`, which are defined (loosely) as

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_flag = models.BooleanField()

class B(models.Model):
    b_flag = models.BooleanField()
    a = models.ForeignKey('A', ...)
```

I want to have a queryset of `A`'s which have `a_flag=True`, and for these, I want further queries to `a.b.filter(...)` be kind of 'pre-filtered' with `b_flag=True`. Is there a way of doing this without redefining the RelatedManager of `B` (still seems like a hacky solution)?

UPD: foreign key was the other way around

Comment: Yes, but this is bad code design. You can prefetch a *filtered* related queryset, but I would renme it to another attribute.

Comment: But you probably have put the `ForeignKey` the opposite way? Since now every `a` has *one* `B`, not the opposite way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [**`Prefetch`**-object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) (not to be confused with the `.prefetch_related(..)` call) and do some filtering at that point.

For example:

```
A.objects.filter(
    a_flag=True
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('b_set', queryset=B.objects.filter(b_flag=True), to_attr='b_pos')
)
```

So now the `QuerySet` will contain a collection of `A`'s that have an attribute `b_pos` that contains the related `B` objects, but with `b_flag=True`.

So given that there are three related `B`s for a given `A` object, but only two have a `b_flag=True`, then `b_pos` will contain these two.

I would really advise *not* to target `b_set` itself, since if you pass an `A` object to a method, that method will assume that `b_set` simply provides all realted `B`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Considering your comment about code design then - if i have an API method which should return filtered `A`'s with inlined filtered `B`'s, how can I do that another way? Passing e.g. `b_lookup='b_with_flag'` to serializer's kwargs?

Comment: @ionagamed: can you in the serializer use a `b_pos= BSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` in the serializer for the `A`?

Comment: this serializer is used not only for this view, so i would like to keep naming the old way (`b_set = BSerializer(many=True, ...)`)

_btw: still can't grasp how do you mention others in comments, your username with @ at the beginning didn't work for some reason_

Comment: @ionagamed: you can create an (inherited) serializer that will do the processing. As a last resort you can of course use the default manager.